# Unexpected end of JSON input When pass JSON data from Spring MVC Method

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring-mvc

When i am attempting to pass JSON Object from Spring MVC controller and then i get that JSON in java script function. It throws javascript error [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input] when parsing data. When i pass just String instead of JSON from Spring MVC method then i get correct data in javascript.

> My JSON From Spring MVC method : {"custName":"Shas","custId":123}

sample.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var test= $('#test');
    alert(test.val()); -> "{" is showing
    alert(JSON.parse(test.val())); -> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" is showing in console
});
```

sample.jsp

```
<input type="hidden" id="test" value="${test}">
```

Sample.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView test(HttpServletRequest request, ModelAndView model) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.setCustName("Shas");
    test.setCustId(123);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    model.addObject("test", gson.toJson(test));
    //model.addObject("test", "test");
    viewURL = "cl/test";
    model.setViewName(viewURL);
}
```

Comment: Put your JSON here, please!

Comment: Quite weird to use `ModelAndView` for a JSON response. Are you sure you aren't responding with an HTML page? ;) I can smell it.

Comment: Bharata i have updated my json. please check it

Comment: sjahan.. i am responding to jsp page [test.jsp].. If set String instead of Test object [JSON]in model then its working fine

Comment: @sjahan i need to return to some view page as well as with 50 fields data to show in that page

Comment: @deadend I'm not sure I completely understand, but nevermind: we still don't know what your server is sending to the browser. If the browser cannot parse JSON, then, it's not JSON. Please show what is in the response of your request so that we can understand what your server is doing wrong.

Comment: @deadend I think you have a design smell with your need to return it to a view page. One URL must return one given thing: either it is an HTML page, to be displayed by the browser, either it is an API and it returns JSON or XML with proper headers, etc. Mixing the two doesn't smell good.

Comment: @sjahan. i am receiving only value "{" in javascript. my requirement is to redirect one view page with the values. so i used ModelAndView object in Spring controller method and am not using any ajax call since calling from URL browser

Comment: How does the "test" object in the model get rendered as something that is supposed to be fetched by $('#test') ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just return the JSON as response?

Change the return type to `String` and add `@ResponseBody` below `@RequestMapping`

Comment: Because i need to return to specific view page [cl/test] with adding some attributes so i have used ModelAndView. This java method when call url hits from browser then redirect to specific view page with data

Comment: i need to return to some view page as well as with 50 fields data to show in that page

Comment: @deadend if your response contains all these things, then how could it be possible to call JSON.parse() on it?

Comment: @kumesana. i am receiving only value "{" in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the string before set it to html.
Use something like this https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml(java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you're trying to execute an ajax request ,in your Javascript you try to show a json value but inside your controller you're returning a view as a response that should be resolved by the InternalResourceViewResolver to get a json response you should alter your test method to return json object and you can passe an id parameter for example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Test test() {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.setCustName("Shas");
    test.setCustId(123);
    return test ;
}
```

Then you can call your ajax method using jquery for example :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // GET REQUEST
    $("#getTestObject").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        ajaxGet();
    });

    // DO GET
    function ajaxGet(){
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : window.location + "/test",
            success: function(result){
                    console.log("Success: ", result);   
            },
            error : function(e) {
                console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            }
        }); 
    }
})
```

And inside your pom dependency you have to add Jackson dependencies

```
   <properties>
        <jackson.version>2.6.3</jackson.version>
    </properties>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: @ Errabi, not using Ajax call. I am hitting the URL from browser then its goes corresponding RequestMapping in Spring MVC controller method, in that method i am retrieving nearly 50 values from DS and setting in ModelAndView object to show in view page.

Comment: I didn't understand the purpose of the javascript function ?